# Unable to compile after upgrading Parse and Bolts frameworks in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk, bolts-framework

I recently upgraded from Parse framework 1.4 to Parse framework 1.6, and I upgraded the Parse framework, the Facebook framework, Bolts framework, ParseUI framework, ParseFacebookUtils framework all to the latest version. I am now getting the error message:

```
Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules"
(deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
/Users/<UserName>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<AppName>-
cqujidljgutxwkaudhsuhqoahrja/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/<AppName>.app
/Frameworks/Bolts.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I am running Mac OS X 10.10.2 and I have Xcode 6.1.1. I downloaded the Parse libraries from https://parse.com/docs/downloads/, and when the Bolts framework refused to compile, I tried compiling manually from the Github page at https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS. Does anyone have any idea how to get this to work? What I've been able to find out so far is that the Bolts framework is missing a plist (info.plist) that OS X is expecting, but when I try to add that plist manually, it says that there is an unexpected item in the root of the folder. I've moved that to the Versions>A>Resources folder, and I get the same error message.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I am apparently an idiot, and I had imported the Parse frameworks as an Embedded Binary instead of a Linked Framework and Libraries. When I fixed this issue, the app compiled successfully. Thanks for your time.